# Position division based on position of another element

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml

I have an submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit_search" id="submit_search" value="Search"/>
```

and I have a division that shows a magnifying glass:

```
<div class="icon">
    <div class="search"></div>
</div>
```

I'm after a JavaScript function which will fire as soon as the page loads which will position the magnifying glass onto of the button.

Is there a JavaScript function that can find the position of an element on a page from its ID so that I can then use that to absolutely position the icon division?

Have I included enough code?

Comment: No attempt at JavaScript code has been given in the question.

Comment: Can you not just edit the CSS of the button instead of using a separate div? There are a lot of guides out there on how to customise input elements: http://blog.formstack.com/2010/customize-form-buttons-with-css/ or http://www.suburban-glory.com/blog?page=140

Comment: What about `<button type="submit"><img src="search.png"></button>`?

Comment: css position:absolute?

Comment: How are the `input` and `div.icon` elements positioned with respect to each other? What does the code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function that adds a bit of HTML into the button like so:

```
function addIconToButton(buttonId){
    var icon = document.createElement('div');
    var search = document.createElement('div');
    icon.className = 'icon';
    search.className = 'search';
    icon.appendChild(search);
    document.getElementById(buttonId).appendChild(icon);
}
```

Use it like:

```
window.onload=function(){
    addIconToButton('submit_search');
};
```

Comment: Where do I put the window bit. Does that just go in script tags or do I need to put somewhere to fire it?

Comment: This works on some of my elements but doesn't seem to work on the submit element. Is there any way to attach it to the submit element?

Comment: This didn't quite fix what I wanted by it was the closest I got. I'll post to full code I used.